# How can I validate length of the assigned associations in ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have an ecto model with `many_to_many` association. I put couple of associated models to the changeset via `put_assoc` and want to validate amount of associated models. How can I do that? Example model:

```
defmodule Content do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  many_to_many :topics, MyApp.Topic,
    join_through: MyApp.ContentTopic,
    on_replace: :delete

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    topics_changesets = Map.get(params, "topics", [])
      |> Enum.map(fn(t) -> change(t) end)

    struct
    |> cast(some_cast_here)
    |> put_assoc(:topics, topics_changesets)
    |> I want to validate minimum and maximum amount of assigned topics here. How can I do that?
  end
end
```

Comment: `|> validate_length(:topics, min: 2, max: 5)` doesn't work?

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work at the first glance

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me if I put it after `|> put_assoc(...)`. Does the validation not work at all if you add that?

Comment: @Dogbert, it doesn't work

Comment: It works, my bad. I was wrong with tests

Answer (score 6):

#### Use `validate_length`:

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  # ...

  struct
  |> cast(your_cast_here)
  |> put_assoc(:topics, topic_changesets)
  |> validate_length(:topics, min: @min_topics, max: @max_topics)
end
```